# Should a new feature pop-up load after page finished?

Tags: navigation, web-app, popup, alerts

When trying to expose a new feature to a site I'm using a pop-up that explains the change. Similar to what Google is doing across their products. An example:
[image: Google webmaster tools]

My question is if it is important to **visually load the pop-up after the page finished loading**, to form some sort of effect that notifies the user this isn't part of the page. I've noticed Google are doing this, but wasn't sure if this is important from a UX perspective, or if it's just how they implemented it from a technical POV.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is to make pop-up noticable for user to take his attention. Animation effects are great for this. The movement is one of the strongest distractors for the human eye.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the popup to introduce the new feature to the user. Make sure that the popup should be **small and effective** and it should make the idea of the user clear about the feature.

Also it should not take long time to load, which is not good from UX perspective.

*If required the user should be able to disable the popup (if it is coming frequently on the screen)*

**UPDATE** : Yes you can load the popup after the page finished loading which will notify the user of the new feature.

Comment: The question is if this is **'UX important'** to load the popup after the page finished loading. I know I 'can' do it, just not sure if this actually makes a real difference.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get the term : **makes a real difference**. Can you please elaborate a bit ?